# Ошибка после нажатия fragment

Tags: android, обработка-ошибок

У меня есть два Fragmenta они открываются по нажатию на кнопки, но после повторного нажатия оно крашится.
Как это исправить?

activity_main xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/color_7">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/View"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/View"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@color/color_1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/color_4"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Fragment One"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Fragment Two"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Fragment fragmentOne;
    Fragment fragmentTwo;
    Button btn1, btn2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fragmentOne = new Handbook_btm();
        fragmentTwo = new Fragment2();

        btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2 = findViewById(R.id.btn2);

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragmentTwo);
                transaction.commit();

            }
        });

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragmentOne);
                transaction.commit();

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Первый фрагмент xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_handbook_btm"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/color_1"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="1dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabRippleColor="#80575039"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/color_1"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/color_6" />

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager_handbook_btm"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Первый фрагмент Java

```
public class Handbook_btm extends Fragment {

    public static Handbook_btm newInstance() {
        return new Handbook_btm();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_handbook_btm, container, false);
        TabLayout tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tab_handbook_btm);
        ViewPager viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.pager_handbook_btm);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        return view;
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Handbook_Tab(), "Handbook");
        adapter.addFragment(new Other_Tab() , "Other");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Второй фрагмент xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Второй фрагмент Java

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_2,
                container, false);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Ошибка

```
2020-07-02 08:46:47.173 5930-5930/com.example.myapplication E/FragmentManager: Fragment no longer exists for key f0: unique id fba40de6-b06a-491b-8fd4-963a47bb640d
2020-07-02 08:46:47.173 5930-5930/com.example.myapplication E/FragmentManager: Activity state:
2020-07-02 08:46:47.183 5930-5930/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 5930
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment no longer exists for key f0: unique id fba40de6-b06a-491b-8fd4-963a47bb640d
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.getFragment(FragmentManager.java:772)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.restoreState(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:324)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onRestoreInstanceState(ViewPager.java:1461)
        at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:15866)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3231)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3237)
        at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:15844)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Fragment.java:573)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.restoreViewState(FragmentStateManager.java:356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1189)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1434)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1497)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:447)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2169)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1992)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1947)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6397)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:939)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:829)
```

Answer (score 0):

Сначала я посоветовал вам использовать `FragmentPagerAdapter` вместо `ViewPager`, и добавить это в свой адаптер:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
}
```

Если это не работает для вас, возможно, вы хотели бы создать свой собственный `PageAdapter` непосредственно наследовать от `PageAdapter`, и скопировать код `FragmentPagerAdapter` в ваш `PageAdapter`. Если вы настаиваете на использовании `restoreState()` и `saveState()`, просто следуйте `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` и отладьте его.